# Are Goalkeepers worse online?

Tags: fifa-21

fifa 21 is my first fifa, so I am not the best player.  When I play single player, or co-op, the goalkeepers seem decent and make saves when they can.  As soon as I play online seasons though, they just stand there, missing saves that any self respecting keeper could stop with his eyes closed.  It doesn't matter how terrible the shot is, or how close it is too them, they just stand there. I'm not usering my goalie.  This leads me to ask, are the keepers in online worse than single player, or are online players just better at making shots?

Comment: What game mode?

Comment: hey @dly, I'm playing seasons.